# pynput does not send ctrl+c to copy selected text

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, clipboard

I am using python 2.7 on win7 64 bits. Here is a code, which just replaces every selected `text` by `<h1>text</h1>`. [pynput-1.6.8](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput) is used for global hotkey and keypress, while [pyperclip-1.7.0](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) is used to handle clipboard.

But I found that in fact, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not pressed at all.

What is the problem? Thanks

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, GlobalHotKeys
import pyperclip

# initilize the clipboard to null
pyperclip.copy('')

keyboard = Controller()

def on_activate_h():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+h pressed')

    # copy current text to clipboard
    # but in fact, it does not on my PC
    # why
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press('c')
    keyboard.release('c')
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)

    txt = pyperclip.paste()
    if txt:
        keyboard.type(f'<h1>{txt}</h1>')

def on_activate_i():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+i pressed')

with GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': on_activate_h,
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+i': on_activate_i}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is still running into this:

The copy doesn't work because the Alt key is still pressed from your global hotkey.

You can simply release the Alt key before triggering Ctrl+C:

```
keyboard.release(Key.alt)

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('c')
keyboard.release('c')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
```

This workaround is not required on Linux or macOS.